# Synergy 1.4.10 client side mouse lag [Windows 7 server, Linux Mint 14 client]

Tags: windows-7, mouse, linux-mint, synergy

I have recently installed Linux Mint 14 on my laptop with Windows 7 64 bit on the server. I've used Synergy before with a windows 7 64 server and a windows 7 32 client and it worked perfectly. I'm pretty confident the problem isn't the server/client configuration.

My problem is that the mouse works perfectly on the server, but when switching over to the client side it starts lagging and moving in choppy movements. I've tried messing around with the server "relative mouse" config, with the mouse properties on both machines, I've searched and I've tried just about everything suggested on this site, nothing works. I'm pretty sure it isn't a network problem, it was working when my laptop had windows (same setup otherwise) and if I reverse the roles (Mint as server, Win as client) the mouse works perfectly on both.

It seems that there's no real answer to this issue but if anyone has any ideas it'd be appreciated. I'm pretty new to Linux so I might have overlooked some configuration somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found the culprit. Essentially this is a network problem, but probably not caused by your connection specifically. The way I solved this was to replace the default Network Manager with **WCID Network Manager**.

http://wicd.sourceforge.net/download.php

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on Ubuntu 12.04 -- I switched from unity to cinnamon desktop and magically all of my problems vanished.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue as Draconicrose that there was a extreme lag when windows(windows10) is the server and linux(lubuntu) is the client, and when they switched there was no lag.
This was mostly solved by installing WCID and uninstallind network-manager on linux. Actually there is still a slight lag though it is much better than it used to be.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.